# Do i need to learn java To build Android Application ? 

Tags: android, cordova

I have to make a project for android tablets, But i don't know if I can use Phonegap instead of learning Java. My application has to:

- Talk with SQL server: update, delete, etc (using web-services) if there is no connection with server application has to store data in local then has to update to remote
- Show current location of user in map (like navigation)
- User can add location or information on the map, (like tracking objects on locations)

Application will use Internet, so application has to be secure, application doesn't have a lot of users maximum users will be 50.

So what do you think? If you work in Phonegap can you suggest me to use it or I have to learn Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer is **No** You don't Have to , You can use PhoneGap or if you are a **.NET** Fan-boy then use [Mono For Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) instead

**PhoneGap**

when you start your new application project you will just need to load your html page to the app and this is all you need to know about java , and from this point you will start implementing in your HTML document using javascript , html , css , phonegap to access mobile APIs , jquery mobile etc

[image]

The best way to Access a remote server data from you "Web based app " is  to make ajax calls to the remote server so keep in your mind that you will use Jquery Mobile (or any other UI frame work that support this functionality )

- [PhoneGap Storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) Provides access to the devices storage options.
- [PhoneGap Geolocation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation) The geolocation object provides access to the device's GPS sensor.

if you will use PhoneGap and looking to have a native look app recommended is [kendo ui](http://www.kendoui.com/mobile.aspx) it is a little pricey $200 but worth it

*plus* what Ridcully said in his answer "If you want to program for Android in earnest, you will have to learn Java and the Android API."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to program for Android in earnest, you will have to learn Java and the Android API.

If this is just a one time task, I think all of the required issues might be doable with Javascript/Phonegap.